# MySQL NOT IN (array[]) vs PHP in_array(array[])?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a query that I run hourly and I am processing a certain dataset from this query. While processing this dataset, I need to ignore some IDs, I am currently doing this with `NOT IN`, but the number of IDs I need to ignore is around 50.

The question I am wondering is, I am creating a text file in a certain pattern with the data I am processing, should I use this ignore operation directly in the query or inside the foreach pattern for better performance?

**Query returns around 5000-7000 data in a dataset consists of 10M record, and I need to ignore around 50 ID from resultset.**

Lets say;

```
$blacklist_arr = array(1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100); //around 50 element in array~
```

---

What I use now;

```
...QUERY...
resultSet.ID NOT IN (\'' . implode( "', '" , $blacklist_arr ) . '\')
```

What I'm planning to use;

```
foreach ($final_dataset as $final_data) {
    ...
    if (!in_array($final_data, $blacklist_arr )) {
    //write to file
    ...
```

**edit***
Query structure is below;

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4,..., a.coln
        FROM
            `a`
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX( b.col4 ) AS X, b.col2 FROM `a` AS `b` GROUP BY b.col2 ORDER BY NULL ) sub ON ( sub.X = a.col4 ) 
        WHERE
            ( a.someColumn > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 2 HOUR ) 
            AND ( a.col3 < DATE_HERE ) 
        ) UNION
        (
        SELECT  a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4,..., a.coln
        FROM
            `a` 
        WHERE
            ( a.someColumn >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ), INTERVAL 3 MONTH ) AND a.col4 IS NULL ) 
            AND ( a.col3 < DATE_HERE ) 
        ) 
    ) AS resultSet 
WHERE
    resultSet.col1 NOT IN ( 1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 ) 
ORDER BY
    resultSet.col3 ASC,
    resultSet.col2 ASC,
    resultSet.col4 ASC,
    resultSet.col1 DESC
```

Comment: Try checking the performance of just the SQL, one with the IN clause and without it.  See how much difference it makes.

Comment: @NigelRen sorry I forgot to mention about it. Query time with/without `NOT IN` is around 0.080 - 0.0100 seconds, right now it looks like it doesn't makes any difference but no of elements in array will increase daily/weekly. Expected no of elements in this array will be 300-500 each year and will be resetted 1 year interval

Comment: Try running it with a larger number of elements, if the difference is negligible then stick with this.  Running a loop with `in_array()` is not particularly effiecient.

Comment: Thank you @NigelRen, I will test with it too, so I better stick with current logic

Comment: If you do end up filtering in the array, the more efficent way around is flipping the blacklist array (values to keys) and using `isset` along the lines of: `$skip = array_flip($blacklist_arr);` and in your loop: `if(isset($skip[$id])) { continue; }`. Will make a difference if you run this in a loop and have a large blacklist.

Comment: P.S. Some stats on the above: Looping 100K random numbers / 1K random number blacklist: 0.03s vs 0.25s for `isset` vs `in_array`. 100K / 10K: 0.03s vs 2.21s. 1M / 1K: 0.15s vs 2.10s. 1M / 10K: 0.15 vs 35.5s. 10M / 100K: 1.58s for `isset`. The `isset` check adds < 5% to the loop baseline runtime so it's quite economical. Less so for `in_array`. Would be curious to see comparable `NOT IN` stats for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the stats @MarkusAO, still haven't decided whether its optimal to move on with `NOT IN` or `isset` though. I will run test queries to see which one is more efficient with your test numbers

Comment: @Pelin your mileage may vary, so just grab the test code and run it yourself so you get locally comparable numbers. I've left the `in_array` function there for comparison. N.B. generating the 10M random numbers into an array sucked up a bit over 500MB of RAM, so you may want to crank up your `memory_limit` if you're testing with larger payloads. https://3v4l.org/0PqDa#v8.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variety of points:

- I have a "Rule of Thumb":  "If a possible optimization is estimated to improve things by less than 10%, move on.  That is, don't spend extra effort on it.  Instead, look for something better to work on."  According to your numbers, the optimization decreases the result set by only about 1%.
- There is a standard programming rule:  "KISS".  Which is simpler to code -- the `NOT IN` or the PHP filtering?  A variant:  "Which approach is fewer keystrokes?"  That comes from "A Programmer's time is much more valuable than computer time.
- Moving the `NOT IN` into each subquery may speed it up *slightly*.  This is because it would decrease (slightly) the intermediate tables involved in the query.  (However, this fails the 10% and KISS rules.)  On the other hand, it could eliminate the outermost Select.  Note:  This works:  `(SELECT ...) UNION (SELECT ...) ORDER BY...`.
- Potential bug:  The innermost Select may be picking a date & time from one of the excluded col1's.
- `UNION` defaults to `UNION DISTINCT`, which is slower than `UNION ALL`.  Consider this as a bigger optimization.
- `ON ( sub.X = a.col4)` probably needs to mention `col2`.
- Is `DATE_HERE` somehow related to `NOW()`?  Perhaps you need `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATETIME` or vice versa?
- I suspect that the `DISTINCT` is not needed.  Anyway, it is redundant with the `UNION`.
- Consider whether the "blacklist" should be a table, not a config file.  As a table, `NOT EXISTS(..)` or `LEFT JOIN .. IS NOT NULL` would need to be added to the query.  This would be slower than what you have now but might be "cleaner".
- `WHERE 1=1` is an artifact of lazy programming; it is *not* an optimization; the Optimizer will simply toss it.
- Often, better indexes provide the most improvement.  *Maybe* the following would help.  Note:  Separate, single-column indexes are *not* as good.  Also, when adding `INDEX(a,b)`, drop `INDEX(a)`.

  ```
  a (as b):  INDEX(col2,  col4)  -- this order
  a:  INDEX(col4, col3, someColumn)  -- col4 first
  ```

Comment: I found much more than what I asked in this answer, it will be of great help both in my current project and future projects. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain in detail! I used `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` for the sake of eliminating any possible duplicate rows

Answer (score 1):

If your `t.col_black_elem` is obtained by another query you could try using a left join an check for not matching value

```
   SELECT a.col1,..., a.coln
   from table1 a 
   LEFT JOIN (
        select col_black_elem from tablex 
   ) t on t.col_black_elem = a.colx 
   WHERE  t.col_black_elem  is null
```

and for your code

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4,..., a.coln
        FROM
            `a`
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX( b.col4 ) AS X, b.col2 FROM `a` AS `b` GROUP BY b.col2 ORDER BY NULL ) sub ON ( sub.X = a.col4 ) 
        WHERE
            ( a.someColumn > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 2 HOUR ) 
            AND ( a.col3 < DATE_HERE ) 
        ) UNION
        (
        SELECT  a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4,..., a.coln
        FROM
            `a` 
        WHERE
            ( a.someColumn >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ), INTERVAL 3 MONTH ) AND a.col4 IS NULL ) 
            AND ( a.col3 < DATE_HERE ) 
        ) 
    ) AS resultSet 
LEFT JOIN (
        select col_black_elem from tablex 
   ) t on t.col_black_elem =  resultSet.col1
WHERE  t.col_black_elem  is null
ORDER BY
    resultSet.col3 ASC,
    resultSet.col2 ASC,
    resultSet.col4 ASC,
    resultSet.col1 DESC
```

Otherwise if your t.col_black_elem  is not obtained  by a another query you could populate a temp table or dynamically build a temp table using several select union

Comment: Thank you @scaisedge. I edited my question and added my query template. So from what I understand is to stick with `NOT IN` is better in my current query. `col1` to `col4` has indexes.

Comment: @pelin   how you get the blacklist ..  you have a query for  get these ids??.. ..anyway answer updated  with your code sample

Comment: I have a config file and these IDs are stored as an array in this file, fetching these blacklist IDs from there. So, not running an extra query for these IDs. Thank you for updated answer, checking it out!

Comment: then you could or use a tempo table  populated  with the blacklist or build a subquery based  on a  set of select union one for each elem in black list ...

Answer (score 1):

From the performance looking point I recomment you:

1. Remove DISTINCT in 1st subquery. One sorting is better then two sortings.
2. Filter your rows in subqueries, not in combined rowset, this will decrease the amount of rows to be sorted by UNION.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4,..., a.coln
        FROM
            `a`
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX( b.col4 ) AS X, b.col2 FROM `a` AS `b` GROUP BY b.col2 ORDER BY NULL ) sub ON ( sub.X = a.col4 ) 
        WHERE
            ( a.someColumn > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 2 HOUR ) 
            AND ( a.col3 < DATE_HERE ) 
            AND a.col1 NOT IN ( 1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 ) 

        ) UNION
        (
        SELECT  a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4,..., a.coln
        FROM
            `a` 
        WHERE
            ( a.someColumn >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ), INTERVAL 3 MONTH ) AND a.col4 IS NULL ) 
            AND ( a.col3 < DATE_HERE ) 
            AND a.col1 NOT IN ( 1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100 ) 

        ) 
    ) AS resultSet 
ORDER BY
    resultSet.col3 ASC,
    resultSet.col2 ASC,
    resultSet.col4 ASC,
    resultSet.col1 DESC
```

Comment: Thank you @akina, should I add `WHERE 1=1` before `ORDER BY` if I use `NOT IN` part in subqueries for faster result?

Comment: @Pelin You may but not must. It doesn't affect anything.